# jquery remain item visible until select another item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submenu

I have a jquery menu with submenus.  Maybe is too simple but I have just a little experience with jquery

I would like to show the submenu at mouse over event, and keep it visible until a diferent menu option be selected.

I'm using a jquery menu I found at http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/jquery_drop_line_tabs/

Here is the code

```
<script src="droplinemenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

//build menu with DIV ID="myslidemenu" on page:
droplinemenu.buildmenu("droplinetabs1")

</script>
<div id="droplinetabs1" class="droplinetabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/"><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/"><span>CSS Examples</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Activities 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Activities 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Activities 3</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Water Sports 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Water Sports 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Water Sports 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Water Sports 1</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">Activities 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://tools.dynamicdrive.com"><span>Tools</span></a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.javascriptkit.com/"><span>JavaScript</span></a>
  <ul>
  <li><a href="#">Traveling 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Traveling 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Traveling 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Traveling 4</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Africa 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Africa 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Africa 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Africa 4</a>
          <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Kenya 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kenya 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kenya 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kenya 4</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Kenya 5</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  <li><a href="#">Traveling 5</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.cssdrive.com"><span>Gallery</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The css file has this:

```
.droplinetabs{
overflow: hidden;
border-bottom: 1px solid gray; /*underline across bottom of main tabs*/
}

.droplinetabs ul{
font: bold 11px Verdana, sans-serif;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
}

.droplinetabs li{
display: inline;
margin: 0 2px 0 0;
padding: 0;
text-transform: uppercase;
}


.droplinetabs a{
float: left;
color: white;
background: #c76023 url(leftedge.gif) no-repeat left top; /*default background color of tabs, left corner image*/
margin: 0 4px 0 0;
padding: 0 0 4px 3px;
text-decoration: none;
letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.droplinetabs a:link, .droplinetabs a::visited, .droplinetabs a:active{
color: white;
}

.droplinetabs a span{
float: left;
display: block;
background: transparent url(rightedge.gif) no-repeat right top; /*right corner image*/
padding: 7px 9px 3px 6px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.droplinetabs a span{
float: none;
}


.droplinetabs a:hover{
background-color: #b05016; /*background color of tabs onMouseover*/
color: white;
}

.droplinetabs a:hover span{
background-color: transparent;
}

/* Sub level menus*/
.droplinetabs ul li ul{
position: absolute;
z-index: 100;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background: #c76023; /*sub menu background color */
visibility: hidden;
}

/* Sub level menu links style */
.droplinetabs ul li ul li a{
font: normal 13px Verdana;
padding: 6px;
padding-right: 8px;
margin: 0;
background: #c76023; /*sub menu background color */
}

.droplinetabs ul li ul li a span{
background: #c76023; /*sub menu background color */
}

.droplinetabs ul li ul li a:hover{ /*sub menu links' background color onMouseover. Add rounded edges in capable browsers */
background: #714421;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;  
-moz-border-radius: 5px; 
-khtml-border-radius: 5px;  
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And the js file has this

```
/*********************
//* jQuery Drop Line Menu- By Dynamic Drive: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/
//* Last updated: May 9th, 11'
//* Menu avaiable at DD CSS Library: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/
*********************/
var droplinemenu={

arrowimage: {classname: 'downarrowclass', src: 'down.gif', leftpadding: 5}, //customize down arrow image
animateduration: {over: 200, out: 100}, //duration of slide in/ out animation, in milliseconds

buildmenu:function(menuid){
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var $mainmenu=$("#"+menuid+">ul")
        var $headers=$mainmenu.find("ul").parent()
        $headers.each(function(i){
            var $curobj=$(this)
            var $subul=$(this).find('ul:eq(0)')
            this._dimensions={h:$curobj.find('a:eq(0)').outerHeight()}
            this.istopheader=$curobj.parents("ul").length==1? true : false
            if (!this.istopheader)
                $subul.css({left:0, top:this._dimensions.h})
            var $innerheader=$curobj.children('a').eq(0)
            $innerheader=($innerheader.children().eq(0).is('span'))? $innerheader.children().eq(0) : $innerheader //if header contains inner SPAN, use that
            $innerheader.append(
                '<img src="'+ droplinemenu.arrowimage.src
                +'" class="' + droplinemenu.arrowimage.classname
                + '" style="border:0; padding-left: '+droplinemenu.arrowimage.leftpadding+'px" />'
            )
            $curobj.hover(
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    if ($targetul.queue().length<=1) //if 1 or less queued animations
                        if (this.istopheader)
                            $targetul.css({left: $mainmenu.position().left, top: $mainmenu.position().top+this._dimensions.h})
                        if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest) //detect IE6 or less, fix issue with overflow
                            $mainmenu.find('ul').css({overflow: (this.istopheader)? 'hidden' : 'visible'})
                        //$targetul.dequeue().slideDown(droplinemenu.animateduration.over)
                        $targetul.dequeue().show()
                },
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    $targetul.dequeue().hide()
                    //$targetul.dequeue().slideUp(droplinemenu.animateduration.out)
                }
            ) //end hover
        }) //end $headers.each()
        $mainmenu.find("ul").css({display:'none', visibility:'visible', width:$mainmenu.width()})
    }) //end document.ready
}
}
```

What I think might be an option is to keep the previous item name and compare it with the new one

I tried changing the hover function like the next but did not work:

```
$curobj.hover(
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    if($anterior!=$targetul)
                    {
                        $anterior.dequeue().hide()
                    }
                    $anterior=$targetul
                    if ($targetul.queue().length<=1) //if 1 or less queued animations
                        if (this.istopheader)
                            $targetul.css({left: $mainmenu.position().left, top: $mainmenu.position().top+this._dimensions.h})
                        if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest) //detect IE6 or less, fix issue with overflow
                            $mainmenu.find('ul').css({overflow: (this.istopheader)? 'hidden' : 'visible'})
                        //$targetul.dequeue().slideDown(droplinemenu.animateduration.over)
                        $targetul.dequeue().show()
                },
                function(e){
                    var $targetul=$(this).children("ul:eq(0)")
                    //$targetul.dequeue().hide()
                    //$targetul.dequeue().slideUp(droplinemenu.animateduration.out)
                }
            ) //end hover
```

Comment: Can you produce a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Yes, here it is  http://jsfiddle.net/yN8Nz/4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what I've done:

1. On `hover` I keep the current visible `ul` in `var prevous;`
2. On `mouseleave` I keep that `ul` visible, but just if the next hover `div` *has no children*

`Hover`

```
if (previous!= null ) {
    previous.css('display','none');
}
```

`End hover`

```
if (previous!= null ) {
    previous.css('display','block');
}
```

**[Demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yN8Nz/5/)**

*Note: this script is quite complex for editing, so i suggest you to find something more simple*

Comment: Thank you, this works for me.  For some other will not work since the submenu has also childs and those hide the first submenu.  Does not matter, for my application if seems to be good enough.